# Logical OR with two if statements

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create Logical OR with two if statements which of which have only one condition.
if(condition1) if(condition2)
My question is about JS. But it should apply across the board.

Comment: "which of which have only one condition" - What?

Comment: `if (condition1 || condition2)` ?

Comment: `if(A){P} else if(B){P}`

Comment: please add the compete statements. what result do you want?

Comment: If you are asking whether you can use || operator in JavaScript between two conditions or not then the answer is "Yes" you can use it in js for if conditions. and if this is not your answer then please elaborate on your question

Answer (score 1):

You basically have to write one if after the other, to construct an AND you would write an if inside the other.

```js
const form = document.forms[0]
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('change', update)
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('change', update)

function update(){
  document.getElementById('result').checked = logical_or(
    document.getElementById('a').checked,
    document.getElementById('b').checked
  );
}
function logical_or(a, b){
  // here is a logical_or implemented with if statments
  if(a){
    return true;
  }
  if(b){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for=a>
<input type=checkbox name=a id=a> a</label> <br>
<label for=b><input type=checkbox name=b id=b> b</label><br>
<label for=result>
<input type=checkbox name=result id=result disabled>a OR b
</label>
</form>
```